# How to pass selected column values to a method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I need your help in passing the selected row columns' values in a `<p:dataTable>` to a method. Now in my code, I am getting incorrect values and some of them are null, so can you please help.

My datatable code is:

```
<p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" value="#{hrd.pendingRequests}">
    <p:column headerText="Request Date">
        <h:outputText value="#{hr.requestDate}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Request No.">
        <h:outputText value="#{hr.reqNo}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Employee Code">
        <h:outputText value="#{hr.employeeCode}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">View</f:facet>

        <p:lightBox style="align:center;" iframe="true" width="1200px" height="600px">
            <h:outputLink value="#{hr.link}">
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{hrd.HRCESS}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{hrd.employeeCode}" value="#{hr.employeeCode}"/>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{hrd.reqNo}" value="#{hr.reqNo}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:outputLink>
        </p:lightBox>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

However if I clicked on the `<p:commandButton>` and I will check the printed values of the `employeeCode` and the `reqNo`. in the `HRCESS()` method, I will find that the `employeeCode` and the `reqNo`. are wrong.

And here is my code in the bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    listPendingRequests = new ArrayList<PendingRequests>();

    try {
        //SQL Statement
        while (result.next()) {
            PendingRequests pendingList = new PendingRequests();
            requestDate = result.getString("ECW_REQ_DT");
            reqNo = result.getString("ECW_REQ_SEQ_NO");
            employeeCode = result.getString("ECW_EMP_CD");
            pendingList.setRequestDate(requestDate);
            pendingList.setReqNo(reqNo);
            pendingList.setEmployeeCode(employeeCode);
            listPendingRequests.add(pendingList);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I will find that the employeeCode and the reqNo. are wrong" What do you mean by wrong?

Comment: Can you please format the code? It's quite unreadable at the moment.

Comment: There was a missing `<p:column>` before the edit - the last `<p:column>` in the `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: I mean by wrong that the employeeCode value in the datatable is 111 and the reqNo. is 564 and while passing it to the method on the click of the commandbutton, the value of the employeeCode is 666 and the reqNo is 999 which is for another row.

Comment: Have you tried the commandbutton without all that weirdness around it (i.e. the lightbox, commandlink etc)? Also, setting a `rowKey` might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSF 2.2 you can pass the values as method parameters.

```
public void HRCESS(String employeeCode, String reqNo)
```